# When I build someone else's code it says `Package Qt5Gui was not found in the pkg-config search path` but i installed it

Tags: cmake, makefile, qt5

I have installed `Qt 5.1.4` but when I 'make install' it shows

```sh
Package Qt5Gui was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `Qt5Gui.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'Qt5Gui' found
Package Qt5Widgets was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `Qt5Widgets.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'Qt5Widgets' found
Package Qt5Multimedia was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `Qt5Multimedia.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'Qt5Multimedia' found
```

But I installed this software `qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.14.0.run`, after I tried to find them I ran `locate Qt5Gui` but no `Qt5Gui.pc` returned,so how can i get `Qt5*.pc` on my `ubuntu 20.04` ?

Comment: Have you installed the Qt development package?

Answer (score 2):

The installation I started was missing a few more packages

The complete installation should look like this

```sh
sudo apt install qtmultimedia5-dev qt5-default -y
```

The construction of the qt compilation environment requires more than the installation package downloaded from the official website

It worked for me !

Now i can find the `Qt5*.pc`  !

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [qtbase5-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/qtbase5-dev) which is part of [qt5-default](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/qtbase5-dev)

see: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/qtbase5-dev/filelist

EDIT: you may also have to install the package [qtmultimedia5-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/qtmultimedia5-dev).

Comment: also qtmultimedia5-dev ！ thanks！